# dead-lock scenario in grails when trying to do ORM

Tags: postgresql, grails, orm

I am writing a simple grails (2.3.1) sample application which uses postgresql(9.1)
I have two domain classes 'Nose' and 'Face'.

```
//Nose class
package human

class Nose {

    static belongsTo=[face:Face]
    static constraints = {
    face nullable: true
    }
}

//Face class
package human

class Face {
    static hasOne = [nose:Nose];
    static constraints = {
           nose nullable: true
    }
}
```

My database is empty and I am using static scaffold.
Now, grails does not allow me to insert into either, because one has foreign key constraint with other.
Also, when i try to insert directly in the postgresql database, i get the same foreign key constraint error:

```
human=# insert into nose (id, version, face_id) values (1, 0, 1);
ERROR:  insert or update on table "nose" violates foreign key constraint "fk33afd3c47bf8db"
DETAIL:  Key (face_id)=(1) is not present in table "face".
```

OR

```
human=# insert into face (id, version, nose_id) values (1, 0, 1);
ERROR:  insert or update on table "face" violates foreign key constraint "fk2fd65d8476fd1b"
DETAIL:  Key (nose_id)=(1) is not present in table "nose".
human=#
```

How to resolve this dead-lock condition ?

Comment: Make the Nose nullable in Face. Since Face "owns" Nose it will have to be created first. I also struggle with sometimes, it can be a hassle.

Comment: It does not work. As you can see in my edit I added nullable constraint in Face domain class. I go this error:
**Batch entry 0 insert into nose (version, face_id, id) values (0, NULL, 4) was aborted. Call getNextException to see the cause.**

Comment: Alright, bugger! What does your DataSource.groovy-setting say - create-drop or update? It should be create-drop (first time) and then you should change it to update after it all "works".

Comment: thats useful info, I will try that d-bugger :)

Comment: The reason I wrote it was because I'm suspecting that you have an old database that's in place, so even if you make the changes in the domains they won't be used.

Comment: I dropped the db and changed conf to create-drop. As you said, since Face owns Nose, I have made Nose nullable in Face. And REMOVED nullable for Face in Nose. And this time it works. Thanks @marko

Comment: Good! Always tricky til you really get your relations straight!